# Calling FB.login with to get permissions throw an error in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm calling in **canvas**:

```
FB.login(function(){}, {
  scope:'publish_stream'
});
```

On Firefox and Chrome shows popup with permission dialog. But on IE there is error (see attach.) :

> An error occurred with my_app_name. Please try again later.

[image]

My `FB.init`:

```
FB.init({
        appId:  <FB_APP_ID>,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml:  true,
        oauth:  true,
        hideFlashCallback: function(){}
    });
```

Earlier (before oauth) I was using code below, it was ok, but it not work wit oauth:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'permissions.request',
    perms:  'publish_stream',
}, function(){});
```

**edit:**

Information from access token:
[image]

**edit2:**

**If you will find a solution, write answer - if it will work, I'll give you 100 points from my reputation.**

Comment: does it make a difference if you add this to the FB.init() function: authResponse:false

Comment: What version of IE do you have installed? Are you emulating an earlier version?

Comment: I tested on IE9, on IE8 and IE7 through IE9 (F12).

Comment: I tested on IE8 (XP Pro SP3) and the emulation of IE7 that comes with IE8.  Both worked OK to post to my timeline.

Comment: But I don't want to post. I want to get permissions to post.

Comment: try a network tool like fiddler to see is the exact error message returned from facebook and post here

Comment: I think this is not possible, because I'm using it with canvas.

Comment: If you are making a GET request, why do you need publish_stream permission?

Comment: I've app which has only `email` permissions on install. `publish_stream` isn't mandatory, if you don't like, you don't have to use it.

Comment: What do you get when you plug that access token into the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

Comment: Can you show us the URL of this page so we can check it out ourselves?

Answer (score 4):

To make it work in IE, you should add channelUrl param to your FB.init with fully qualified url. For example:

```
FB.init({
    appId:  <FB_APP_ID>,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml:  true,
    channelUrl: 'http://www.example.com/facebook-channel.html'
});
```

The url must point to a page that contains just only one script tag:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

It's important to make channelUrl an absoulte, if you just write

```
channelUrl: '/facebook-channel.html'
```

It wont work. I've got a lot of headache with it, so I hope it'll be helpfull for you or anybody who troubled with it like me before.

Comment: This worked for me!!! didn't include protocol in my case. Adding http: did the trick. Thanks a gajillion. Tried everything but this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch  _inCanvas to `true` and see what happens

```
FB._inCanvas = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem in the past. You are probably opening it on a domain that is not the same as the one specified as your site domain on the application settings page.

Comment: I tried all possible domains, but in all cases it failed. I also test it with using **website url**.

Comment: I think this is most probably way to resolve this issue, so I reward it, howewer another 100 rep. is awaiting for winner:)

Answer (score 1):

If you have selected to use

> sandbox

in developers.facebook.com/apps.

You should change it to not use.

Answer (score 0):

Now you’re running on https you will need to reference all assests over https. IE will now show a load of warnings telling the user not all content is sent over the secure connection. This is probably why your popup fails. Set the SDK to load stuff over HTTPS:

```
      FB._https = true;
      FB.init({
       /* your app id and stuff */
     });
```

Comment: Yes I understand that but he's running a canvas HTTPS session that may be retrieving stuff via HTTP. Remembering its running in a frame on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because IE not setting 3rd party cookies?

try adding

header('P3P: CP=HONK');

into php file, header function has to come before anything in file is output.

Answer (score 0):

I done walkaround for that. I'm opening new window with url like:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APPID&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=MYPAGE`

When MYPAGE (which is in my app url) is loaded it simply closes itself.

---

**If you will find a solution, write answer - if it will work, I'll give you 100 points from my reputation.**